# UrlRewrite condition based on custom HTTP header

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I'm trying to configure a rule in UrlRewrite that has 2 conditions:

- HTTP header `HTTP_HOST` needs to match a certain domain (api.contoso.com)
- A custom HTTP header `x-app-version` needs to be present in the HTTP request

based on this info, I'd like to redirect to a different version of the API in the back-end.

**Problem**
The rule is behaving as expected on the first condition. 
It kicks in when `HTTP_HOST` matches api.contoso.com.
However, it ignores my custom `x-app-version` header.

**Assumption**
So, I fear that a UrlRewrite condition only can be defined in combination with the limited set of predefined HTTP headers from the dropdown (`HTTP_HOST`, `REMOTE_ADDRESS`, `REMOTE_HOST`, …)

**Question**
Is assumption correct or should this be possible whatsoever? 
Is there a mistake in my config or other approach to have conditions based on a custom defined HTTP header?

```xml
<rule name="ARR_test2" enabled="false">
  <match url="(.*)" />  
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="api.contoso.com" />
    <add input="{x-app-version}" pattern="1" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="https://FARM_apiv1/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Ok, I found out how to use custom HTTP headers in a UrlRewrite condition:

- custom headers need to be preceded by "HTTP_".
- substitute dashes with underscores

E.g.: in order to retrieve my custom header "x-app-version", I can use "HTTP_x_app_version".
So my UrlRewrite config should look like this

```
<rule name="ARR_test2" enabled="false">
  <match url="(.*)" />  
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="api.contoso.com" />
    <add input="{HTTP_x_app_version}" pattern="1" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="https://FARM_apiv1/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

It's actually mentioned quite clear in the documentation:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: According to the documentation, you can use `HEADER_x-app-version`. when using IIS newer than 5.1. (I used `pattern=".*"` to perform a simple check for a custom header.)

Comment: Actually, the pattern to verify the existence of a custom header should be `.+` (one or more) instead of  `.*` (zero or more).