# IIS - request blocking rule

Tags: asp.net, iis

Anyone knows how to create a blocking request rule in IIS that do not meet the following requirements?

- custom header HTTP_MyMandatoryHeader must be present
- value of HTTP_MyMandatoryHeader must be a specific value

I tried with following IIS Url rewrite rule, but all requests are blocked with this.

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="RequestBlockingRule1" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_MyMandatoryHeader}" pattern="^123$" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="403" statusReason="Forbidden: Access is denied." statusDescription="You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied." />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

[image]

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UrlRewrite condition based on custom HTTP header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43050026/urlrewrite-condition-based-on-custom-http-header)

Comment: Indeed, I had the HTTP_, but missed the substitute dashes with underscores.

Comment: You don't necessarily need substitute dashes with underscores, you can also refer to this link: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/setting-http-request-headers-and-iis-server-variables#allowing-server-variables-to-be-changed).